# Words or phrases that describe a person who is blind to the consequences of their actions

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm trying to find either a word or a phrase that describes a person who who is blind to the negative consequences of their actions even though the consequences should be obvious to them.

Answer (score 9):

[oblivious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/oblivious):

> not aware of or not noticing something, esp. what is happening around you:
>   *She was often oblivious to the potential consequences of her actions.*

Answer (score 1):

Thoughtless.

"We are so thoughtless, that we thus wander through the hours which are not here, regardless only of the moment that is actually our own."

Blaise Pascal

French mathematician, physicist (1623 - 1662)

Answer (score 0):

**inconsiderate**:

> 1. lacking in concern for the rights or needs of others; thoughtless.
> 2. not carefully considered or thought out.

Funk and Wagnalls. Standard desk dictionary. 1969

Answer (score 0):

Someone that is blind to the consequences of their actions is "Ignorant", though the contextual clues suggest that a better word to use might be "Naive" as it refers to one that is specifically unaware of the "consequences" of their actions rather than lacking a general "understanding" of their actions. Naive also entails that the person is "blind" to consequences (in a negative sense) of their actions and so can only see the "positive" outcome of what they do.

Some synonyms of the word ignorant are as follows (quoted from [Oxford Thesaurus of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=CaCcAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA437&lpg=PA437&dq=%22without+knowledge,+unaware,+unconscious,+insensible;+unfamiliar+with%22&source=bl&ots=64xIumYBPg&sig=ACfU3U3DjlCwZuRwzUwmnbNuBTniy1kn3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy77-ZwYPhAhWyCDQIHaL8DK0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22without%20knowledge%2C%20unaware%2C%20unconscious%2C%20insensible%3B%20unfamiliar%20with%22&f=false)).

> without knowledge, unaware, unconscious, insensible; unfamiliar with, unacquainted with, unconversant with, inexperienced in, uninitiated in, blind to, oblivious to, naive about, innocent about, green about, a stranger to; uninformed about, unenlightened about, unschooled in; *informal* in the dark about, clueless about, not knowing the first thing about, not having the faintest about; *literary* nescient, strange to
>   "I was largely ignorant of the effects of radiotherapy"

Comment: Hello. I added block quote formatting for the content in your answer that you drew directly from the _Oxford Thesaurus of English_, along with a link to the source online and a cite explicitly crediting it. English Language & Usage tries to be stringent about crediting sources for quoted language, but new site participants are sometimes unclear about how to credit them properly.

Comment: @Sven Yargs thank you ! I am still learning so it is always appreciated when I am able to see the "errors of my ways" so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

Optimistic and 
Sanguine: *optimistic or positive, especially in an apparently bad or difficult situation.*

Comment: I think those mean they are aware and conscious of the consequences but are choosing to accept them, but I am looking for words or phrases that indicate they are unconscious or unaware even though it should be self-evident.

Answer (score -1):

can't see the forest for the trees.